# Phing - imported build file does not execute

Tags: phing

New to phing, I feel dumb but when I import one build file into another. The imported build file does not execute. I must have something wrong (note that $ phing --buildfile imported.xml runs fine).

I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myproject" default="project" basedir="." description="Set up project">
    <target name="project">
        <echo msg="Deploy" />
    </target>
    <import file="import.xml"/>
</project>

AND

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myproject" default="project" basedir="." description="Set up project">
    <target name="project">
        <echo msg="Deploy" />
        <import file="import.xml"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I have many issues with imported files. I split my build process per component to avoid a very big build file, but I have duplicated entries when I execute phing -l

Comment: If you have problems executing an imported task that is unique, try to execute it without the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I see that you have to make a  inside the default target.

so now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myproject" default="project" basedir="." description="Set up project">
    <target name="project">
        <echo msg="Deploy" />
        <phingcall target="importedTarget" />
    </target>
    <import file="import.xml"/>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is with the "namespaces". I explain you my case, that could be yours.

I have a build.xml file that imports this structure:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── phing
│   │   ├── qgpl
│   │   │   ├── console.xml
│   │   │   └── folder.xml
│   │   └── skel.xml
```

importing these tasks at the bottom of build.xml

```
<import file="${tasks.dir}/phing/skel.xml" optional="false" />

<import file="${tasks.dir}/phing/qgpl/console.xml" optional="false" />
<import file="${tasks.dir}/phing/qgpl/folder.xml" optional="false" />
```

If the file bin/phing/qgpl/console.xml is defined with:

```
<project name="qgpl.console" basedir="${build.dir}" >
```

I get the targets duplicated:

```
phing -l

Buildfile: build.xml
 [property] Loading etc/config.ini
 [property] Loading etc/local-config.ini
 [property] Loading etc/after-local-config.ini

Default target:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 build                      Build the application

Main targets:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 base64Encode               Convertim a Base64 una cadena preguntada

 [...]

 qgpl_console.base64Encode  Convertim a Base64 una cadena preguntada
```

But if there is only one base64Encode target in the project, I must to execute it with

```
phing base64Encode
```

because

```
phing qgpl_console.base64Encode
```

do nothing, no errors but nothing executed.

I fix it removing the project name keyword in the imported files

```
<project basedir="${build.dir}" >
```

And adding the "namespace" in each target

```
<target name="qgpl.console.base64Encode" description="Convertim a Base64 una cadena preguntada" >

    <input propertyname="stringPlain">Input string to convert to Base64</input>
    <qgpl.base64Encode string="${stringPlain}" returnProperty="string64" />
    <echo>${string64}</echo>
</target>
```

I was searching in the documentation, but I don't found other way to do it.